# Pls help cookie account forgotten after reinstall of ubuntu

Tags: support, user-accounts

After reinstalling ubuntu it forgot the cookies of my unregistered account https://askubuntu.com/users/18267/amith?tab=accounts .I'd like to restore this account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While we can't restore it - I have merged it with your new account which will give you access to all the items from your old account under you newly create account.

Comment: For future reference, on the login page, there is a "click here to recover your account" link.